# Bucle for para crear funciones

Tags: javascript

En el programa que intento optimizar tengo 3 funciones que siguen la misma estructura pero con distintos nombres, me gustaría poder hacer un bucle for, declarando tantas funciones como botones tenga dentro del formulario.

El formulario tiene 3 botones, por tanto, 3 funciones.

El programa lo tengo con una class en javascript, por lo que no me deja hacer el bucle fuera de lo que no sea una función:

```
class cls0{

   constructor(id, idtxt, params){

      var tem = document.querySelectorAll("template");

        this.id=id;

      let f0 = document.createElement('div');
      f0.innerHTML = tem[3].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(f0);

      this.contentForm = f0.querySelector(".content-form");

      f0.querySelector(".btn-event-sndFrm").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         //this.sndFrm();
         console.log('Hola');
      });

      f0.querySelector(".btn-event-addFrm").addEventListener("click",()=>{
         //this.addFrm();
         //this.sndFrm();
         console.log('Adios');
      });

      f0.querySelector(".btn-event-delFrm").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         //this.delFrm();
         console.log('Aaron');
      });

      for (let i in params){
         var hi0 = document.createElement('input');
         hi0.type = 'hidden'; //cambiar a text si hay que verlo
         hi0.name = i;
         hi0.value = params[i];

         f0.querySelector('form').appendChild(hi0);
      }

      this.structure();
   }

   structure(){
      var ff = document.f0.querySelectorAll()
   }
}
```

Hasta ahora lo que he intentado es, desde el final del constructor, hacer una llamada directa a la función structure()

Lo malo es que no se sacar la variable `f0`, y realmente tampoco se si es la manera correcta de hacer lo que quiero.

Comment: ¿Quieres crear funciones dentro del ciclo o solo asignar los eventos que corresponden a cada botón? Por otra parte, si quieres usar `f0` en otros métodos de la clase, en lugar de `let f0 = ...` usa `this.f0 = ...` para crearla como propiedad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar un arreglo que tenga el identificador de botones y también será el nombre de la función a ejecutar. Todo esto en el constructor:

```
// Crear arreglo con identificado re botones y función
const buttons = ['addFrm', 'delFrm', 'sendFrm'];

// Para que f0 esté disponible en otros métodos:
this.f0 = document.createElement('div');

// Recorrer para asignar eventos
buttons.forEach(btn => {
    let button = this.f0.querySelector('.btn-event-' + btn);
    // Asignar función a ejecutar, enlazando instancia de la clase
    button.addEventListener('click', this[btn].bind(this));
});
```

En la primera iteración del ciclo `btn` contiene `addFrm`, por lo que se selecciona el botón con clase `.btn-event-addFrm` y se ejecuta el método `this['addFrm']()`, que es equivalente a `this.addFrm()`.

Por supuesto, debes crear los métodos para cada botón, solo un ejemplo:

```
class cls0 {
    constructor(/* parámetros */) {
        /* Todo el código necesario, incluyendo asignación de eventos */
    }
    addFrm() {
        // Instancia de la clase
        console.log(this);

        // Acceso a otras propiedades
        console.log(this.f0);
    }
}
```

### Actualización:

Para crear solo un método para todos, nada recomendable **<sup>1</sup>**:

```
// Recorrer para asignar eventos
buttons.forEach(btn => {
    let button = this.f0.querySelector('.btn-event-' + btn);
    // Asignar función a ejecutar, enlazando instancia de la clase
    button.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this));
});
```

Tu método:

```
clickHandler() {
    // Saber qué botón desencadenó el evento
    let btn = event.target;
    // Analizar por clase para realizar acciones
    if(btn.classList.contains('btn-event-addFrm')) {
        // Agregar
    } // else if para analizar resto de botones
}
```

**<sup>1</sup>**: No es recomendable tener las acciones de todos los botones en una única función porque, probablemente te ahorres un par de líneas de código, pero el costo va a ser muy alto, complicando la lectura, comprensión y mantenimiento.

En la medida de lo posible, trata de crear funciones que cumplan con el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica). A veces puede ser difícil, pero te va a ayudar a crear mejores códigos.

Comment: De esta forma, según llego a ver, seguiría haciendo tres funciones con la misma estructura no? La intención en todo esto es ahorrarse código, y si sigue una secuencia exacta, como es el caso, hacer una estructura que cambie dependiendo de a qué botón des, un bucle con if else creo que sería, vaya, pero bueno, me has dado una pista de por dónde empezar, a ver si me sale. Muchas gracias =3

Comment: @Aaronibio, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Muchas gracais @Triby